# CSP not allowing me to run JS in a packaged HTML file

Tags: firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to run a simple JS function (in `index.js`) in a regular HTML file, but I keep getting this error: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).`

I tried inserting this `<meta>` tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'index.js'"/>
```

I also tried putting the JS code in the `<script>` tag and replacing `index.js` with `self`, but no luck. I also tried using a "nonce", but it also didn't work. I'm new to web/extension development and I didn't even know CSP existed, so please provide a beginner-friendly explanation.

I'm running the extension as a temporary add-on through `about:debugging` (local).

Comment: Try setting "script-src 'self'", which will allow only scripts loaded from the same source.

Comment: I tried that, it's in the question. This question is already answered though.